# Getting access denied on cloud-bosh-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy micro bosh in EC2 as per http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/ec2/

I am getting `(AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied)` when executing `bosh aws create`

Also URL http://cloud-bosh-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/ returns the following:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>zzzzzzzz</RequestId>
  <HostId>xxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is there any obvious bit of configuration that I am missing?

Thanks

Michal

Comment: You might want to try asking on the [bosh mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-dev).

Comment: I just posted a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653901/error-setting-up-cloudfoundry-2-on-aws-awss3errorsaccessdenied) with a little more detail. If I get an answer I'll repost what I find here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue when following the same guide. It turns out that the issue is that the S3 bucket that is created (which generates its name from the `BOSH_VPC_SUBDOMAIN` you created in the `bosh_environment` file) **has to be unique**.

Changing that subdomain to something *very* specific should get the process rolling again.